# Submit in input set amount of time

Tags: javascript, input

Is it possible to submit something into a input field with javascript to a set amount of time? For example, I want to submit Hello World in a input field every minute then submit it. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Input fields are intended to be filled by the user, not automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it **every** minute this should work:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "Hello World";
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); // form containing "myInput"
}, 60000);
```

Comment: It seems like its working, but trying out in console I keep getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: That would happen if the element can't be found by getElementById. Have you changed the ID in my example to match your code?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Use `setTimeout` and provide a function that fills the input field and submits the form.

Unless you submit via Ajax, this will do a page refresh, but that will reload the timer automatically (assuming you end up on the same page).

If you're submitting via Ajax the timeout function should reload/reset the timer, providing itself as the function parameter.

Roughly (jQuery for convenience):

```
$(function() {
    function doit() {
        $("#input_id").val("Hello World");
        $("#form_id").submit();
    }

    setTimeout(doit, 1000 * 60);
});
```

More Ajax-y:

```
$(function() {
    function doit() {
        $.post(postUrl,
               $("#form_id").serialize(),
               function () {
                   setTimeout(doit, 1000 * 60);
               }
        );
    }

    setTimeout(doit, 1000 * 60);
});
```

(More or less.)

Comment: Hm, of course. Maybe you can provide an example please? And would this be possible in a bookmark extension that isn't part of the page?

Comment: @Trippy Little details like that... probably good to know up-front.

Comment: I guess this wouldn't really work if I submit this in Chrome's js console?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend atleast try once before posting question, this will help you only

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval("submit_from()",60000);
});

function submit_from()
{
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) will call some code every X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var t=setTimeout("$('#form_id').submit();",3000);
 });
```

try this.